# It is said that Mercurial's "hg clone" is very cheap... but it is 400MB on my hard drive? (on Mac OS X Snow Leopard)

Tags: mercurial

I have a project I cloned over the network to the Mac hard drive (OS X Snow Leopard).

The project is about 1GB in the hard drive

```
du -s
2073848 .
```

so when I `hg clone proj proj2`

then when I

```
MacBook-Pro ~/development $ du -s proj
2073848 proj

MacBook-Pro ~/development $ du -s proj2
894840  proj2

MacBook-Pro ~/development $ du -s
2397928 .
```

so the clone seems not so cheap... probably around 400MB... is that so?  also, the whole folder grew by about 200MB, which is not the total of proj and proj2 by the way... are there some links and some are not links, that's why the overlapping is not counted twice?

Comment: by the way I found that `du -sh` a better way to find out the size in MB.  it will print something like 406MB

Comment: Consider also the time it takes - while `hg clone` does more than "checkout" does in centralized SCM, it can take more than 10x as long to download the entire history than to do a single checkout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When possible, Mercurial will use hardlinks on the **repository** data, it will not use hardlinks on the **working directory**. Therefore, the only space it can save, is that of the `.hg` folder.

If you're using an editor that can break hardlinks, you can `cp -al REPO REPOCLONE` to use hardlinks on the entire directory, including the working directory, but be aware that it has some caveats. Quoting from the manual:

> For efficiency, hardlinks are used for
>   cloning whenever the source and
>   destination are on the same filesystem
>       (note this applies only to the repository data, not to the working
>   directory). Some filesystems, such as
>   AFS,
>       implement hardlinking incorrectly, but do not report errors. In these
>   cases, use the --pull option to avoid
>       hardlinking.
>
> In some cases, you can clone repositories and the working directory
>   using full hardlinks with
>
> ```
> $ cp -al REPO REPOCLONE
> ```
>
> This is the fastest way to clone, but it is not always safe. The
>   operation is not atomic (making sure
>   REPO is not
>       modified during the operation is up to you) and you have to make sure
>   your editor breaks hardlinks (Emacs
>   and most
>       Linux Kernel tools do so). Also, this is not compatible with certain
>   extensions that place their metadata
>   under
>       the .hg directory, such as mq.

Answer (score 3):

Cheap is not the same as free.  Cloning creates a new repository, that inherently has space costs - if you didn't want it to be located somewhere else on the disk, why would you bother cloning?  However it is cheap in comparison, as you note, cloning your 1GB repo only adds ~200MB to the space taken up in the parent directory, because Mercurial is smart enough to identify information that doesn't need to be duplicated.

I think more generally, you need to stop worrying about the intricacies of how Mercurial (or any DVCS/VCS) works.  It is a given that using version control takes more disk space, and takes time.  As the amount of data and number of changes increases, the space and time demands increase too.  What you're failing to realize is that these costs are far outweighed by the benefits of version control.  The peace of mind that your work is safe, that you can't accidentally screw anything up, and the ability to look at your past work, along with the ease of distribution in the case of DVCS's are all far more valuable.

If your concerns really outweigh these benefits, you should just stick to a plain file system, and use FTP to share/distribute/commit the source code.

**Update**

Regarding romkyns' comment: You're downloading a large quantity of data.  Downloading lots of data takes time, regardless of what it is.  There is no way around that fact, and no way Mercurial nor any other VCS can make it go faster.

The benefit of Mercurial and the distributed model however is that you only pay that cost once.  Since all work is done locally, you can commit, revert, update, and the like to your hearts content without any network overhead, and only make network operations to pull and push changes, which is relatively rare.  In a centralized VCS, you're forced to make network operations any time you want to do something with your source code.

Additionally, I just tried cloning mozilla-central myself to see how long it would take, and it took 5 minutes to download changesets and manifests, 20 minutes to download the file chunks, and then updating to default (which is not network limited) took 10 minutes.  35 minutes to get the entire codebase for Mozilla along with the entire history of revisions isn't that bad.  And even on this massive project with ~500,000 files and ~62,000 changes the repository is only 15% larger than the working directory, which goes back to the original point of the question.

It is worth mentioning though, cloning a repository is *not* the best way to download source code.  If you just want the codebase, you can get [releases](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Developer_Guide/Source_Code/Downloading_Source_Archives).  The [Mercurial Web Interface](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories) can also let you [browse the codebase](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/) without downloading anything, and you can download complete archives of any revision via the archive links (bz2, zip, gz) at the top of each page.  All of these options are faster than a full clone.  Cloning the repository is only necessary [when you want to actively develop](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Developer_Guide/Build_Instructions#Get_the_source) the Mozilla codebase, not when you just want the files.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I certainly appreciate the benefits of distributed VCS, but when I use both types on a daily basis I really rather miss the speed of initial checkout on centralised VCS. As for mozilla-central, I ended up doing exactly what you said - I only started the clone because Mozilla suggests this as the best way. It's ironic though that I ended up in a worse state than a centralized VCS allows: this "checkout" is completely disconnected from everything, whether I'm online or not.

Comment: I'm not sure where you saw Mozilla saying cloning is the best way to get the codebase, since the "actively develop" link above says otherwise.  I'm confused by what you mean about being "completely disconnected" though.  Do you mean because you can't push changes back?  Because that would be true if they used a centralized VCS as well.  If you checkout a SVN repository that you don't have commit privileges on, you end up with little more than the files themselves.  By cloning a Mercurial repository, you get all the benefits of VCS on your computer.

Comment: Rather than trying to answer the question, this is just a condescending lecture based on the dubious assumption that the user is criticizing the merits of using a VCS at all. I understood the OP to just be trying to understand how Mercurial works, which is important if you want to use it correctly. The long "Update" section is about a comment from romkyns which apparently no longer exists.

Comment: @JonCoombs thank you for the feedback; I appreciate your critiques, and would probably not have phrased my answer this way today.

Answer (score 0):

When you can get 1TB of disk space for £60, 400MB is cheap (~ 2p).

Comment: (in USD that's $88 for 1TB, so ~3 cents for 400 MB)

Comment: a concern here is not the space -- it is the time it takes to create a repository.  And making 5000 new copies of files can make the hard drive head work quite hard too.

Comment: How long does it take?  It can't be all that terribly long.  And I really wouldn't worry about hard drive load like that, it may seem like a lot to you, but just like the price, it's trivial.

Comment: @dimo414 I have been checking out Firefox mozilla-central for three hours now, over a broadband connection. It has only just started loading "files", so I'm probably in for at least three more hours. That is certainly "terribly long" in my book.